# How to set JTextField as a selected component

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am developing an application which have a JTextField, JButton and JTextArea in same JFrame. How do I set JTextField selected when JFrame starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I set JTextField selected when JFrame starts.

I assume you mean you want the text field to have `focus` so you can start typing into it. ("Selected", in Swing terminology, means the text contained in the text field will be highlighted.)

The first component on the frame (top/left) will gain focus automatically.

If your text field isn't the first component then you can request focus with code like:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
textField.requestFocusInWindow();
```

The key is that you need to make the focus request AFTER the frame is visible.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. I always made the focus request before the frame is visible.